# Can linear transformation of variables cause unboundedness of a linear programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-transformations, linear-programming

Let $x$ be a $n$ $\times$ $1$ variable. Then I have a linear programming which is assumed to be bounded and has a solution:

$$\max c^Tx$$
$$s.t. Ax \leq b $$

Now I apply a linear transformation on $x$, i.e., $x$ now becomes $Tx$, where $T$ is the transformation matrix. Then the linear programming becomes:
$$\max Tc^Tx$$
$$s.t. ATx \leq b$$

Here I am curious as to whether there would exist a $T$ that causes this new LP to be unbounded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. By boundedness, you have $x\leq U$ for all $x$ such that $Ax\leq b$ for some bound $U$. So if $ATx\leq b$, then $y=Tx$ satisfies $Ay\leq b$, and thus $Tx=y\leq U$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. At the last term you wrote, do you mean $Tx = y \leq TU$?

Comment: @Goodolddays No. Actually, I see now that $\max x$ in your question is not defined since $x$ is a vector. In the question it should read $\max cx$ for some cost vector $c$. Then boundedness in my answer is given by $cx\leq U$ and I will be showing $cTx=cy\leq U$.